# How do you reference a attribute field and output results onto a different attribute field?

Tags: python-3.x, arcgis-js-api

[image]

Here is what i am trying to do....

STATUS     STATU_DESC
1          Occupied
2          Not Occupied
3          Busy
4          No Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that something like this should work:

```
def calc_status_desc(status):
    if status == 1:
        return 'Occupied'
    elif status == 2:
        return 'Not Occupied'
    elif status == 3:
        return 'Busy'
    elif status == 4:
        return 'No information'
    else:
        return None
```

In the field calculator select python and invoke it like this,
`calc_status_desc(!STATUS_DESC!)`

[calculate field example](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm)

Comment: the picture below is the correct code, thanks for your help cabesuon!